# How to relate the middle table with One or Many relationship?

Tags: database-design

I am currently developing a simple CRM system. These are my tables: `user`s, `roles`, `role_users`, `customers`.

[image]

Rules:

- A user can only be assign with a single role
- A role can have a 1 or many users
- A Customer is assigned to a user

Question: 
Did I mark the correct relationship in the screenshot above?

Comment: Missing one rule: If a Customer is assigned to a User, can a User have many Customers?  Or is it really a customer has one User ID and that User ID is used by only one customer?

Answer (score 1):

If a user can have no more than a single role, and this will ever change, then put `role_id` directly on the `user` table, then the relationship between `role` table and `user` table is a single role to many users.